# npm ci command failing with "Cannot read property '@angular/animations' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

While performing docker build for my Angular project, In the **npm ci** step, I'm getting below error:
`Cannot read property '@angular/animations' of undefined`

As there is no proper error, we are unable to find the solution.

**Versions of package and node:**

- @angular/animations - 15.2.9
- Node.Js - 18.14.2
- NPM - 9.5
- Angular Cli - 15.2.8

**What I have tried till now:**

- Cross check package.json file for Animations module
- Try downgrading the @angular/animations version
- Deleting package-lock.json file and node_module directory
- Deleting cache and tried

**DockerFile:**

```
FROM docker-images.artifactory.dummydomain.com/db/node:14.18-alpine as build

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@15.2.8
RUN npm ci 
RUN ng build --configuration=test
USER node
COPY --chown=node:node . .
```

**Package.json Files dependencies:**

```
    "@angular/animations": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/localize": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/material": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/router": "^15.2.9",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.9.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.2",
    "export-from-json": "^1.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^6.7.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng-uikit-pro-standard": "^1.0.0",
    "ngx-spinner": "^15.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.7",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.5.4",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.6.9",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "vkbeautify": "^0.99.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.2.8",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.2.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "^15.2.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.9.5"
  }
```

It would be great if someone can help. TIA!

Comment: What happens when you run `npm ci` locally? By "Deleting package-lock.json file", do you mean you removed it and let it be generated again by running `npm install`?

Comment: Probably the error comes together with a stack trace, could you add it to your question?

Comment: @JSONDerulo - If I run npm ci locally, it works fine. And for your second question, answer is yes.

Comment: are you sure that you are using node 18.14.2 (the docker image in your example is `node:14.18-alpine`

Comment: Are you sure `package-lock.json` file exists before `npm ci` is run ?

Comment: @tony Yes, package-lock.json file exist before npm ci run

Comment: @griFlo Yes installed nodejs is 18.14.2. Still I will try updating node image in docker file

Comment: @EliasSoares - No more error logs thn pasted above. :(

Comment: @umehta try to log more information with `npm ci --verbose`

Comment: This is due to the lockfile version differences between npm bundled with node 14 vs the one bundled with node 18. Your docker image needs to use the same version supported by the already created lockfile. npm ci will fail to install when it detects these differences.

Comment: @griFlo As you pointed, issue was with Node version. I had to update it to 18.14.2 from 14.18. Thanks!

Comment: @griFlo "are you sure that you are using node 18.14.2 (the docker image in your example is node:14.18-alpine", this is what I experienced from time to time so I added an answer for that. Please take a look.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This error occurs if npm tries to process a lockfile which it cannot understand (the error message is not helpful at all). The format of the lockfile is changing over time, and npm marks the current version with the [`lockfileVersion`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/configuring-npm/package-lock-json#lockfileversion) parameter in the lockfile:

- No version provided: an "ancient" shrinkwrap file from a version of npm prior to npm v5.
- 1: The lockfile version used by npm v5 and v6.
- 2: The lockfile version used by npm v7 and v8. Backwards compatible to v1 lockfiles.
- 3: The lockfile version used by npm v9 and above. Backwards compatible to npm v7.

You are using v14.18 as a base image, which is shipped with npm v6. In your system you have npm v9, so the `lockfileVersion` is 3. As you can read in the above list, this format is not compatible with npm v6.

The recommended fix would be to update the version of the Node base image to v16 (npm 8) or v18 (npm 9). Alternatively, you could perform an `npm install` using npm v8, and commit + push the resulting lockfile.

Comment: excellent answer! github actions is such a puzzle.

Comment: I hit this error from time to time. I added an answer to further explain what I have experienced.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is to ensure everyone/everything is using the same version node/npm

Answer (score 0):

For me JSON Derulo's answer was the key.  I had node v14.x in my strategy: matrix: node-version block.  Removing it in the .yaml file got past the error:

was:

strategy:
matrix:
node-version: [14.x, 16.x]

changed to:

strategy:
matrix:
node-version: [16.x]

You don't need the strategy matrix if you're only running one node version. See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/automating-builds-and-tests/building-and-testing-nodejs#specifying-the-nodejs-version

Answer (score -1):

@JSONDerulo's answer has explained it all (the root cause) but I would like to add some words about the practice of putting `package-lock.json` in git, which is probably the direct cause of the problem.

As we all know we should commit `package-lock.json`. But I have hit the problem with it from time to time that some of the team member uses the latest nodejs (now it is nodejs 20), generating an updated `package-lock.json`, check-in while another guy may still uses old nodejs, say 14, then, bam, all of sudden he fails to run `npm ci`.

Or the dockerfile still uses `FROM node 14 ...` or GitHub action uses `node-version: [14.x, 16.x]` suddenly fails.

So now we have a simple rule that one commit only contains the updated `package-lock.json` (no code change) and in commit message, it needs to say with which nodejs version we have this updated lock file.