# GitHub Actions failing all workflows with various errors each time I am using it for testing

Tags: testing, npm, build, github-actions

Error:

```
Run npm ci
npm ERR! Cannot read property '@testing-library/jest-dom' of undefined

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2023-06-09T17_12_13_249Z-debug.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Workflow:

```yaml
name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x, 16.x, 18.x, 20.x]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm run build --if-present
      - run: npm test
```

Directory structure:

[image: dir]

I have checked the path of the JSON files, checked the JSONs and amended the structure of my project. Nothing worked. I would appreciate the help. I have been trying to fix it for two days now.

Comment: Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76255847/4036946

Answer (score 0):

Review your node version. In my case was v20.6 and I used only 20.x version in de node docker workflow.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).